# Infinite page reload with Vue when redirecting to external authentication URL

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

Here is what I'd like to implement in my Quasar 2 / Vue 3 application:

1. User visits any route.
2. Upon each route change, a backend call is made to check if the user is still authenticated.
3. If the user is not authenticated, she shall get redirected to the external URL of the authentication provider.

This is my current approach:

```js
router.beforeEach(() => {
api.get('/api/user/current').then((response) => {
    userInfoStore.authenticated = true;
    userInfoStore.givenName = response.data.givenName;
    userInfoStore.fullName = response.data.fullName;
}).catch(() => {
    userInfoStore.authenticated = false;
});

if (!userInfoStore.authenticated) {
    redirect('http://localhost:8555/oauth2/authorization/keycloak');
}
});
```

However the following problems occur:

1. The app constantly reloads itself.
2. The call to `/api/user/current` gives `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` in the browser console.
3. The console shows `Changed to http://localhost:8555/oauth2/authorization/keycloak` but gives this error message.

`ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk src_layouts_MainLayout_vue failed.`